# How to import swift pod class into objective C UIView class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ytl' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ytl

  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.20’
  pod "AXWireButton"
  pod "DGActivityIndicatorView"
  pod  use_frameworks!  “RaisePlaceholder”
end
```

I created the **Swift** `RaisePlaceholder`, now I want to import in `Objective-C` class  `UIView` Class.

How can I import **Swift pod** class into objective-C UIView Class?

Your input will be appricated.

Comment: #import not working?

Comment: If you are not using bridging header, use that to import

Comment: Which project is this? Objective C project or Swift project?

Comment: Yes import not working Its a objective-C project.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `@objc` before your Swift class like below

```
@objc class YourSwiftClass: UIViewController
```

Now in your project & targt settings, change below flags to **YES**

> Defines Module : YES
>
> Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries : YES
>
> Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES

Now clean your project `COMMAND+K` now import in your objective C file like regular import

```
#import "YourTargetName-Swift.h"
```

**Note:** If your target name contains spaces, replace them with underscores (example: "Sample Project" becomes "Sample_Project-Swift.h"). Another point to note, in fact, that is not your project name instead your **target name**

Link to **Apple Docs**: [How to use Swift code in Objective C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)